# Does a 64 OHMS Headphones require an amplifier?

Tags: audio, headphones, amplifier, sound-quality

I recently bought a pair of HD7 from Presonus (https://www.presonus.com/products/HD7) which are 2 x 32 ohms headphones. They sound good but not as good as I though they would.

Would that be due to the fact that I am using my headphones directly to my phone/ Laptop? Would it required to be driven by an amplifier to get a better sound quality out of them?

I guess my question might sound a little bit stupid but I could not really find anything about 64 Ohms headphones.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given that the headphones are low impedance, I would say, no you do not need to use an amplifier, in fact I would recommend against that as low impedance headphones are more susceptible to "blow-outs" when using amplification.

Low impedance headphones are typically what's used for phones or laptops since those devices do not have much amplification. The perceived lack of quality could just be that the audio hardware in your laptop or phone aren't very high quality. It could also be that the source material you are listening to is not high quality. And lastly, it could just be that the headphones aren't that great, though in my experience and opinion Presonus tends to have quality speakers and headphones.